# In a Jmeter JSR223 sampler how do you access the values set in the HTTP Request Defaults configuration object?

Tags: jmeter

I am using groovy as the language and want to read the server IP value is that was set in the HTTP Request Defaults configuration item.

I looked at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html and a few other places but nothing useful I can find.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no such thing as HTTP Request Defaults in JMeter script, it is only abstraction layer made for your convenience. When the test is being run the values are merged into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers where the relevant field(s) is(are) blank. So instead of getting the server IP value from HTTP Request Defaults you should be getting it from the HTTP Request samplers.

I would recommend using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), add it as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and use the following code:

```
def serverIP = sampler.getDomain()
```

It is also possible to do using JSR223 Sampler for the previous sampler (which is supra in the Test Plan) like:

```
def serverIP = ctx.getPreviousSampler().getDomain()
```

See [Why It's SO Important To Use JMeter's HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) to learn more about HTTP Request Defaults specifics.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. That makes sense why I couldn't find documentation that let me read those values directly. The idea of storing the value in a variable through a JSR223 PostProcessor makes sense. I have a call to do a login so I can just put the postprocessor after that and then have my sampler to make the calls I want to do and use the serverIP variable previously set.